# Similarity of orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

Prove that for any $M$ in $SO(3)$, there is a matrix $P$ in $SO(3)$ and a real $\alpha$ such that

$$PMP^{-1} = \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        \cos\alpha  & \sin\alpha & 0 \\
        -\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\
             0       &     0       & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right]
$$

I think it's easy to prove but I don't remember it!

Comment: The eigenvalues of $M$ are $\pm 1$.  Since $\det M = 1$, at least one of the three eigenvalues must be $1$.  This means $M$ has a fixed point... can you finish from here?